# PHP Redirecting and getting path from URL

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to build a URL shortener in PHP on Apache using XAMPP.

So my URL is localhost.

People request shortened pages like this:

`localhost/url-code`

However, I am not sure how to get this URL code in PHP as it would just show an invalid page (404 not found).

In Flask (Python) I can do `app.route("/<url-code>")` to get the parameter but how do I do this in PHP. Please advise.

I know that RewriteEngine exists but is it useful in this case?

Comment: make it redirect all requests to index.php. Then let PHP get the URL which was actually entered by the user, and process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess and then $_GET["url"] variable:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-z]+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

or just use $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

or parse_url();

for redirecting:
header("Location: $target_url");